# WPF dashed line display different thickness

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpfdatagrid

I'm doing custom datagridrow style, but i get different thickness result when program running.

Custom DataGridRow Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="BackgroundRow" BorderThickness="0">
                    <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid Height="48">
                            ...
                        </Grid>
                        <Line
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Stroke="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
                            StrokeDashArray="4"
                            StrokeThickness="0.5"
                            X2="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But the result when program running, it will show different thickness dashes line. it's happened in random row.

[image: Randomly happened render different thickness dashes line]

Comment: Have you tried setting the UseLayoutRounding=False and SnapsToDevicePixels=True?

Comment: @AwkwardCoder tried but still same

Comment: Setting `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on your line element should sort it out